# Way to grab specific container from Ajax jQuery Call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a way to make an Ajax call with jQuery to call a specific page, grab only a specific container on the page that is being called, and inject the data from that container into a new container? Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Something like:

```
jQuery.get('index.html', function (data) {
  $('.container').html($(data).find('.container'));
});
```

However, it seems a bit strange to do this. The standard is to use your application server to format the results (and only return the results that will be substituted.

Comment: thanks, i thought i had read, that you could do so, with .load(), but i think i misinterpreted what i had read.